# How do I toggle a SwiftUI toggle when a view is tapped?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to toggle a Toggle when a view is tapped. Right now I have the following code and it works, though the Toggle doesn't animate the transition. What can I do to fix?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var toggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $toggle) {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            print("Tapped!")
            self.toggle.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried to wrap the `self.toggle.toggle()` line around a `DispatchQueue.main.asynch`, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it with animation as below

```
}
// .contentShape(Rectangle())    // << add to make full-area tappable
.onTapGesture {
    print("Tapped!")
    withAnimation {
        self.toggle.toggle()
    }
}
```